# C editor with text formatting and context awareness

Tags: c, editor

I am looking for a .c editor that has:

1) text formatting, for example to set some line to bold/italic or different color

2) context awareness
For example I would like to automatic highlight for a code section.
For example between the call to function A and the call to function B to have a different background color.
If I call function A

Or if I am using a local variable that is not initialized to have the variable name marked in red.

Do you know any editor with such features?

Thank you.

Comment: On what platform? Linux? Unix? Windows? Mac? Your cellphone? A casio calculator?

Comment: SO is not the site for such questions. This one is though: http://www.slant.co/topics/?search=text%20editor and there are probably other similar sites

Answer (score 2):

I could suggest you a hell lot with syntax highlighting.Sublime on linux,windows notepad ++ on windows,visual studio etc.

But when considering your second requirement I realise that not many editors satisfy the condition and it is better for you to use vim and modify it accordingly.

A few links i can post which will help you achieve the same [C/C++ ide using vim](http://www.alexeyshmalko.com/2014/using-vim-as-c-cpp-ide/)

Another one to refer is this question from SO itself [Vim for C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149558/recommended-vim-plugins-for-c-coding)

Thanks

Comment: I've been coding in (relatively unmodified) vim for years! there is nothing better.

Comment: I modified vim's python extension to work as expected not the same way you want it but a lower upgrade.Have you tried emacs? I have heard its much more extensible than vim.Currently i am using sublime for all sort of developments it gives satisfactory results.

Comment: do check this one out. Its an emacs modification.
[1] http://tuhdo.github.io/c-ide.html

I am gonna try this one out it seems extremely good!!@AndreasGrapentin

Comment: I have to admit I have never tried emacs. but you know what they say - know both, don't hate at least one =)

Comment: lol i used to fanatically hate  emacs till i started sicp on mit ocw and loved it afterwards.I think with this mod on emacs i might change my opinion!! :)

Answer (score 0):

> Or if I am using a local variable that is not initialized to have the variable >name marked in red.

That actually sounds like Intellisense or some other smart code checking.
You can try Microsoft Visual C++ Express and just save files as '*.c' instead of '*.cpp'.

You can try as well CodeBlocks, CLion (commercial), Code (not as smart, but lightweight and cross-platform).